¿Por que al usar mat-paginator dentro de un dialog y avanzar a los siguientes registros se deshabilitan los botones para la pagina siguiente y regreso
    <div *ngIf="!showAddConsumoForm">
    <h1 mat-dialog-title>Detalle Venta</h1>
    <div class="row" style="width: 100%;">
      <div class="col-md-3 offset-md-9 text-right">
        <button mat-raised-button color="primary" (click)="showAddConsumo()">Agregar Consumo</button>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div mat-dialog-content>
      <table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" class="mat-elevation-z8">
        
        <ng-container matColumnDef="nombre_comensal">
          <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Nombre Comensal</th>
          <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let consumo">{{ consumo.nombre_comensal }}</td>
        </ng-container>
  
        <ng-container matColumnDef="cantidad">
          <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Cantidad</th>
          <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let consumo">{{ consumo.cantidad }}</td>
        </ng-container>
  
        <ng-container matColumnDef="producto">
          <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Producto</th>
          <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let consumo">{{ consumo.nombre_producto }}</td>
        </ng-container>
  
        <ng-container matColumnDef="divisa">
          <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Divisa</th>
          <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let consumo">{{ consumo.nombre_divisa }}</td>
        </ng-container>
  
        <ng-container matColumnDef="subtotal">
          <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Subtotal</th>
          <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let consumo">{{ consumo.subtotal }}</td>
        </ng-container>
  
        <ng-container matColumnDef="total">
          <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Total</th>
          <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let consumo">{{ consumo.total }}</td>
        </ng-container>
  
        <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
        <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></tr>
      </table>
      <mat-paginator 
  [length]="totalConsumos" 
  [pageSize]="pageSize" 
  [pageSizeOptions]="[5, 10, 15]" 
  showFirstLastButtons 
  (page)="onPageChange($event)">
</mat-paginator>
    </div>
  </div>

tengo este codigo dentro de un dialog y carga correctamente los registros para este ejemplo tengo 11 registros y muestra de 5 en 5 y al momento de avanzar a los siguientes 5 registros si los muestra pero deshabilita por completo las opciones para avanzar y retroceder, tengo que cerrar el dialog y volverlo a abrir y ya se habilitan pero vuelve a ocurrir lo mismo si cambio de pagina y no se que hacer.

El problema fue algo ajeno a angular, era que no me estaba devolviendo todos los registros desde la consulta porque se paso el uso de LIMIT entonces me perdi en cuanto a enviarle esos parametros desde el front y yo ocupaba que se cargaran todos los datos en el dataSource ya que no son muchos.
P.D. Si seran muchos datos si es preferible manejarlo con limit y offset y enviar los parametros desde el front.
